# Most common use cases for the HTML5 shiv/shim JS script

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, shim, html5shiv

I often see people suggesting I include the [HTML5 shiv JS script](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) to make HTML5 work in Internet Explorer but I can't find a clear explanation for the most common use cases this will cover.

Might someone give **common** scenarios of why one would need this JS script?

Also, does it need to be in the `<head>` or can I put it with the rest of my JS at the bottom of the `<body>` tag such that it doesn't block the UI thread?

Comment: here are some links that may answer your questions.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275580/modernizr-vs-html-shiv

http://www.themightymo.com/2012/03/23/how-to-include-html-shiv-properly/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internet Explorer prior to version 9 refuses to apply any CSS styling to HTML elements it does not recognise, this includes the new elements brought in by HTML5. By creating the elements through the JavaScript DOM it suddenly and magically realises that the elements should indeed be styled.

You can write a naive and simple script that loops over an array of HTML5 tag names you want calling `document.createElement(tagName)`. This may work for you in most cases, however, printing HTML5 pages in IE and adding HTML5 content through innerHTML will cause you further problems at which point it would be an idea to switch to the shiv.

HTML5 shiv can, to my best knowledge, be placed in the head or after the body tag if you prefer. I would recommend using conditional comments so that only IE loads it.

Comment: -@Stuart, thanks great explanation, which versions of IE can't style HTML5 elements? Would you mind adding that to your answer?